# Extreme Value Theorem over the Real Numbers

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis

I'm stuck on where to start with this.  I can tell it is to do with the extreme value theorem, but past that point I'm stuck.  Any help would be appreciated.

If $f(x)$ is continuous on $\mathbb{R}$, with $f(x) \geq 0$ $\forall x \in \mathbb{R}$ and $\lim_{x \to - \infty} f(x) = 0 = \lim_{x \to \infty} f(x)$, then $\exists x_0 \in \mathbb{R}$ where $f(x) \leq f(x_0)$  $ \forall x \in \mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If $f$ is identically zero we are done - every point is maximal. Therefore assume $f(x_1)>0$ for some $x_1$. By the limit condition, there exists $a,b$ with $f(x)<f(x_1)$ for all $x<a$ and also for all $x>b$. On the compact interval $[a,b]$, $f$ assumes its maximum at some point $x_0$. Then $f(x_0)\ge f(x)$ for all $x\in \mathbb R$.

Comment: The key insight here is that you can cut off the infinite tails where the function is small and work with a closed interval which is compact and where you have a theorem you can use. You need to deal with the zero case as an exception. It is often the case that you have to divide a problem up into bits - for example, big bits where a function is under control, and small bits where it doesn't matter what the function does because they are so small (or as here, where you know enough to prove a bound).

Comment: Thanks Hagen and Mark.  Your explanations were wonderfully helpful.  Much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Hints:

$$\exists\,R\in\Bbb R^+\;\;s.t.\;\;\forall\,x\in\Bbb R\;\;with\;\;|x|>R\;,\;\;f(x)<0.1$$

Apply now [Wierstrass Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extreme_value_theorem) for $\;f\;$ on $\;[-R\,,\,R]\;$

Comment: What if, coincidentally, $f < 0.05$ on $[-R,R]$, and $f(R + 1) = 0.09$?